# Copy production database to staging heroku

Tags: heroku

How can I pull my production database to my staging server on heroku?

I have two remotes, production and staging.

From the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups) it appears that I want to run `heroku pg:copy COBALT GREEN --app sushi` but it isn't clear what all the arguments mean. How can I copy my production database to my staging database?

Answer (score 7):

First use:

```
heroku pg:info -a your_production_app
```

to retrieve the name of the environment variable that has the URL of your production db, e.g HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL.

Then:

```
heroku pg_info -a your_staging_app
```

to get the same for your staging app (e.g. DATABASE_URL).

Finally:

```
heroku pg:copy your_production_app::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL DATABASE_URL -a your_staging_app
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a clarification to the @Yoni Rabinovitch's answer.

I do not have  named database so I needed to replace  name with DATABASE_URL instead. It is not much intuitive to duplicate DATABASE_URL, is it?

So instead of:

```
heroku pg:copy your_production_app::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL DATABASE_URL -a your_staging_app
```

I used

```
heroku pg:copy your_production_app::DATABASE_URL DATABASE_URL -a your_staging_app
```

Hope this might help somebody.